# How to pass data when using Nested Recycler View

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have been trying to figure it out for a few days now and I still can't solve it.

I created a 3-layer nested recycler view and the display is okay.

1st layer is CartStoreAdapter
2nd layer is for it's CartItemAdapter
3rd layer is for the product's CartItemAddonAdapter

My problem is that. I want to display the total price of all the products per store(including the addon prices) considering the qty aswell. But I can't seem to pass the total Price variable (

```
totalItems += subTotal;
```

) to the CartStoreAdapter.

I tried creating a public method within the CartItemAdapter. When I use Log.d within the viewholder of CartItemAdapter,

```
2023-02-02 17:25:36.773 19606-19606/ph.kaminarigo.app D/totalItems: 522.0
2023-02-02 17:25:37.028 19606-19606/ph.kaminarigo.app D/totalItems: 532.0
2023-02-02 17:25:37.120 19606-19606/ph.kaminarigo.app D/totalItems: 660.0
2023-02-02 17:25:37.178 19606-19606/ph.kaminarigo.app D/totalItems: 1485.0
2023-02-02 17:25:37.230 19606-19606/ph.kaminarigo.app D/totalItems: 1785.0
```

shows up properly. But when I use the variable in the method. It's already zero even before I access that method in the CartStoreAdapter.

```
public class CartStoreAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartStoreAdapter.ItemRowHolder> {

    private List<CartStoreModel> storeDataList;
    private Context mContext;
    private int rowLayout;
    private CartItemAdapter cartItemAdapter;

    public CartStoreAdapter(List<CartStoreModel> storeDataList, Context mContext, int rowLayout) {
        this.storeDataList = storeDataList;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CartStoreAdapter.ItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, parent, false);
        return new ItemRowHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CartStoreAdapter.ItemRowHolder holder, int position) {
        final CartStoreModel singleItem = storeDataList.get(position);
        holder.bind(singleItem);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != storeDataList ? storeDataList.size() : 0);
    }

    public class ItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView tvStoreName, tvStoreTotal;
        RecyclerView rvStoreItems;

        public ItemRowHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvStoreName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvStoreName);
            rvStoreItems = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rvStoreItems);
            tvStoreTotal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvStoreTotal);
        }

        public void bind(CartStoreModel singleItem){
            tvStoreName.setText(String.valueOf(singleItem.getNama_merchant()));

            CartItemAdapter cartItemAdapter = new CartItemAdapter(singleItem.getCartItem(), mContext, R.layout.cart_item);
            rvStoreItems.setAdapter(cartItemAdapter);
            rvStoreItems.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

            double total = cartItemAdapter.getTotalItems();
            Utility.currencyTXT(tvStoreTotal, String.valueOf(total), mContext);
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class CartItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartItemAdapter.ItemRowHolder>  {

    private List<CartItemModel> itemDataList;
    private Context mContext;
    private int rowLayout;
    private double totalItems;

    public CartItemAdapter(List<CartItemModel> itemDataList, Context mContext, int rowLayout) {
        this.itemDataList = itemDataList;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CartItemAdapter.ItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, parent, false);
        return new ItemRowHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CartItemAdapter.ItemRowHolder holder, int position) {
        final CartItemModel singleItem = itemDataList.get(position);
        holder.bind(singleItem);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != itemDataList ? itemDataList.size() : 0);
    }

    public double getTotalItems(){
        return totalItems;
    }

    public class ItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView tvProductTitle, tvMainPrice, tvPromoPrice, tvSubTotal, tvQty;
        ImageView imgThumbnail;
        RecyclerView rvCartItemVar;
        Button btnDeduct, btnAdd;
        CheckBox cbSelectItem;

        public ItemRowHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvProductTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductTitle);
            tvMainPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMainPrice);
            tvPromoPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPromoPrice);
            imgThumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgThumbnail);
            rvCartItemVar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rvCartItemVar);
            tvSubTotal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSubTotal);
            btnAdd = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
            btnDeduct = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDeduct);
            tvQty = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvQty);
            cbSelectItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbSelectItem);

        }

        public void bind(final CartItemModel singleItem){

            CartItemAddonAdapter cartItemAddonAdapter = new CartItemAddonAdapter(singleItem.getCartItemVar(), mContext, R.layout.cart_item_variation);
            rvCartItemVar.setAdapter(cartItemAddonAdapter);
            rvCartItemVar.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

            double activePrice, promoPrice, addOnPrice, itemCost, subTotal;
            int itemQty = singleItem.getQty();

            if(Constants.use_glide) {
                Glide.with(mContext)
                        .load(Constants.IMAGESITEM + singleItem.getFoto_item())
                        .apply(new RequestOptions().override(250, 250))
                        .into(imgThumbnail);
            } else {
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(Constants.IMAGESITEM + singleItem.getFoto_item())
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder)
                        .resize(250, 250)
                        .into(imgThumbnail);
            }

            if(singleItem.getHarga_promo() > 0){
                promoPrice = singleItem.getHarga_item();
                activePrice = singleItem.getHarga_promo();
                tvPromoPrice.setPaintFlags(tvPromoPrice.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                tvPromoPrice.setTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            } else {
                promoPrice = 0;
                activePrice = singleItem.getHarga_item();
                tvPromoPrice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            addOnPrice = cartItemAddonAdapter.getTotalAddonPrice();

            itemCost = activePrice + addOnPrice;
            subTotal = itemCost * itemQty;
            totalItems += subTotal;
            tvProductTitle.setText(String.valueOf(singleItem.getNama_item()));
            tvQty.setText(String.valueOf(itemQty));
            Utility.currencyTXT(tvMainPrice, String.valueOf(activePrice), mContext);
            Utility.currencyTXT(tvPromoPrice, String.valueOf(promoPrice), mContext);
            Utility.currencyTXT(tvSubTotal, String.valueOf(subTotal), mContext);

            Log.d("totalItems", String.valueOf(totalItems));
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class CartItemAddonAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartItemAddonAdapter.ItemRowHolder> {

    private List<CartItemVarModel> addOnsDataList;
    private Context mContext;
    private int rowLayout;

    public CartItemAddonAdapter(List<CartItemVarModel> addOnsDataList, Context mContext, int rowLayout) {
        this.addOnsDataList = addOnsDataList;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CartItemAddonAdapter.ItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout,parent,false);
        return new ItemRowHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CartItemAddonAdapter.ItemRowHolder holder, int position) {
        final CartItemVarModel singleItem = addOnsDataList.get(position);
        holder.bind(singleItem);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != addOnsDataList ? addOnsDataList.size() : 0);
    }

    public double getTotalAddonPrice() {
        double totalAddonPrice = 0;
        for(CartItemVarModel addon : addOnsDataList){
            totalAddonPrice += addon.getVar_price();
        }
        return totalAddonPrice;
    }

    public class ItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView tvVarGroup, tvItemVar, tvPrice;

        public ItemRowHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvVarGroup = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvVarGroup);
            tvItemVar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvItemVar);
            tvPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
        }

        public void bind(CartItemVarModel dataList){
            tvVarGroup.setText(dataList.getGroup_name());
            tvItemVar.setText(dataList.getVar_name());
            Utility.currencyTXT(tvPrice, String.valueOf(dataList.getVar_price()), mContext);

        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to save the changes in the model but I still can't access it outside of the itemviewholder.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I would try to create the CartStoreModel items with the total prices inside each item and initialize them before I pass them to CartStoreAdapter.

Recommend to use ViewModel to calculate the prices and attach them to CartStoreModel items before you send them to CartStoreAdapter.

```
public class StoreViewModel extends ViewModel {
    public ArrayList<CartStoreModel> getItemsWithPrices(){
        for(CartStoreModel item : items) {
            int totalItemPrice = item.price;
            int totalItemAddonPrices = item.getTotalAddonsPrices()// calculate the prices
            item.totalPrices = totalItemPrice + totalItemAddonPrices
        }
    }
}
```

Recommend to do it in another Thread (not the Main Thread) in case you have a lot of items in your list...